# Retrieve dependencies source code in maven project

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

In my maven project I have plenty of dependencies which source code I need to get.

I know there is **maven-dependency plugin** with **unpack-dependencies** goal in it

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>resolve-dependecies</id>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>sources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>sources</classifier>
                <includeParents>true</includeParents>
                <type>java-source</type>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>src-dependencies</id>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>sources</classifier>
                <failOnMissingClassifierArtifact>false</failOnMissingClassifierArtifact>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/Utils/src</outputDirectory>
                <type>java-source</type>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But when I use it a lot files *"have NOT been resolved"*.

e.g.

```
...
org.jboss:jboss-parent:java-source:sources:5
org.apache.cxf:cxf-parent:java-source:sources:3.0.3
org.apache:apache:java-source:sources:13
org.apache:apache:java-source:sources:9
org.liquibase:liquibase-parent:java-source:sources:3.5.0
org.apache.commons:commons-parent:java-source:sources:5
org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:jetty-orbit:java-source:sources:1
...
```

In pom.xml I didn't specify any repository for dependencies, so by default maven central repository is using.

I also tried to decompile (**Fernflower**, **Procyon**, **JAD** projects) my project jar file which contains all dependencies. But after decompiling hundreds of errors appeared in result java files.

I still hope to solve this issue using maven tools.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**

Unresolved artifacts directly not specified in pom.xml

Comment: do you have the maven settings.xml configured?

Comment: @Vijay no, I don't

Comment: is maven downloading other dependencies specified under <dependencies> ?  wondering if its a problem connecting to central repository.

Comment: Why do you need to get the source code? Why not using the jar files? What is the purpose of that?

Comment: @Vijay Actually, all dependencies directly specified in dependencies are retrieved. Probably those which cannot be resolved are "dependencies of dependencies" (?)

Comment: @khmarbaise I have a requirement to build project on proprietary OS

Comment: why do you need this goal? <goal>sources</goal>.  For your requirement, I guess you just need unpack-dependencies

Comment: @Vijay Yes, unpack-dependencies goal is enough, I used source goal only for displaying unresolved dependencies list

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of dependencies with `*-parent`. Given the name I guess these are merely parent poms which probably don't contain any java sources. For the remaining ones, are you sure that there are artifacts with the java sources?

*UPDATE:* I checked the list you shown within your question whether there are sources and there weren't. What I noted is that all of them have packaging `POM`. You might skip these by including `<includeClassifiers>sources</includeClassifier>` within your configuration

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, I'm not sure, I can't find those artifacts as well. Besides, as far as I'm concerned, in retrieved java code there are reference to artifacts, which not given in unresolved dependencies list :\
e.g. import org.osgi.framework.wiring.BundleWiring;

Comment: What is the scope of those unresolved dependencies. It might that they are set to provisioned.

Comment: What happens if you remove `<type>` attribute of dependency plugin.